# Keep displaying conditionalpanel after condition is reactively changed

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I have a conditional panel that is used to update the conditions for it. However, I need the panel to keep appearing even after the update

I tried adding an additional condition that relies on the input from the conditional panel. I also tried to add the input from condition to the condition

```r
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
     title = 'Time inputs in Shiny',
     div( id = "eg1",
          fluidRow(
               radioButtons("ca",
                            "choices",
                            c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"),
                            "B",
                            inline = T),
               conditionalPanel(
                    condition = "input.ca == 'C' || input.ca == 'D' || input.ca == 'E'",
                    radioButtons("cb", "test",
                                 c("Positive", "Negative"), "", inline = T)
               )
          )

     )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
     observe({

          if(!is.null(input$cb)){
               if(input$cb == "Positive"){
                    updateRadioButtons(session, "ca",
                                       "choices",
                                       c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"),
                                       "A",
                                       inline = T)
               } else if(input$cb == "Negative"){
                    updateRadioButtons(session, "ca",
                                       "choices",
                                       c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"),
                                       "B",
                                       inline = T)
               }
          }
     })
}



shinyApp(ui = ui,server = server)
```

as expected the conditional panel will disappear after the update